# Vertical alignment for figures

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> [image: Page 1]

and

> [image: Page 2]

My question is why the first figure is not vertically centered and how can I make it centered **without changing the `htbp` parameter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pad the figure with some vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \vspace{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Another, maybe even better option would be to pad the image with `\vfill`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\null
\vfill
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\vfill

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice you need \null at the start to give LaTeX something to reference to.

As to **WHY** this phenomenon occurs. I'd say it would have to do with the way LaTeX typesets from the top of the page down. If you add `\newpage` or `\clearpage` between the two images then the second one will not be centered either.

The first page is a normal page in which it positions the figure here[h] and on top[t]. The second page is a figure page[p] in which the figure is centered. If you define `\newpage` the second page would be a "normal" page and the figure would be also put at the top.

**-- EDIT --**

The best option relies on [the page FAQ](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-floatpages). Set the counter `totalnumber` to 0 so that each figure will be pushed to a figure page, even if it is the first and can fit with the text. Also, define a very large separation between the floats `fpsep`, to force each float to its own page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{totalnumber}{0}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fpsep{\textheight}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\lipsum[1-2] %with or without text, the figure will get pushed to a float page

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is a sort of a hack: Setting the counter to 0 basically means that LaTeX simply cannot put the figure here[h], on top[t], or on bottom[b]. This is because you cannot have text and a figure on the same page. It forces any figure to go to the floats page.

Comment: Thank you for your time. You're right, I could use the `\vfill` trick you mentioned. Is there a way to automate the detection of this scenario (in my real world example, I use a complex environment as a wrapper for figure and I don't want to add `\vfill` by hand).

Comment: You could use this https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-floatpages. But it only works if the first figure only has p

Comment: Please add the FAQ reference to your answer. Maybe the best option, finally. Thanks.

Comment: While working on that I found the perfect solution. I'm editing it in.